# length of char array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
char data[512];
```

for clearing my array use:

```
memset(&data[0], 0, sizeof(data));
```

I defined:

```
#define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))
```

but when I tried to get the the number of my array, it still gives 512;

```
int a = NELEMS(data);
```

I want to  clear my array, then I add some element, How can I get the number of element inside my array (element inserted)?

Comment: memset just sets the values within the data-array, does not affect the array-size at all

Comment: Are you confusing the size of the char array (which is 512) with the length of a zero-terminated C string (which after setting everything to zero should be zero)?

Comment: "How can I modified to get zero here???"  Huh?

Comment: If you want to know the length of the zero-terminated string of characters in `data`, use `strlen(data)`. If that's not what you want, then you need to make it more clear what you're after. `sizeof` is the size of the data type.

Comment: There's no point of speculating. Let the OP clarify their post through an edit. It is not possible to answer the question as it currently stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is an array of 512 `char` variable (1 byte), so the `sizeof(data)` is 512. This is correct. Read more about data types.

Comment: I clear it by memset, I want to know number of element...

Comment: @H'H if you know the array is `NULL` terminated, you can use `strlen()` to count the number of _valid_ elemnts. Anyway the __total__ number of element will be unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be only 'emptying' the array, and not **removing** it.

`data` will always be `sizeof 512` as that is what you've initialized it. 'clearing it' of contents doesn't resize it, only **deleting** and recreating it will change size.

What you may want instead is

- iterate through until a '`null`' value is found (gets number of elements)
- recreate a new array (with a different size) - not the best option

or, depending on what you're looking for

- set `a = 0;`

---

As it stands, it looks like you wish to add a value to the next available space, and so the first bullet point here should be what you're looking for.

LINK:

[Iterating through an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19062804/3913686)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to count the values you actually added to your "array".

If "data" is supposed to be a "string", and you want to know the number of bytes in your string, you can try strlen(data), assuming you always have a null-terminated content. But I doublt this is what you are trying to do.

If you(re looking for the first non-null char in your array, you will need to iterate using a WHILE loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of how much you have in the array;

```
void add_char_to_array(char array[], unsigned int *index, char input)
{
    array[(*index)++] = input;
}

void clear_array(char array[], size, unsigned int *index)
{
    memset(&array[0], 0, size);
    *index = 0;
}

int main()
{
    char data[512];
    unsigned int index = 0;

    //do stuff

    clear_array(data, sizeof(data), &index);

    add_char_to_array(data, &index, a);
    add_char_to_array(data, &index, b);
    add_char_to_array(data, &index, c);
    add_char_to_array(data, &index, d);
}
```

this will result in an `data` containing: `['a','b','c','d','\0','\0','\0'...]` and `index` will contain `4` (the number of items in the array)

Answer (score -1):

The `memset()` call zeroes out all elements of your array. (A string-processing function normally looks for `0` (equals `'\0'`))

Still that does not mean, that your array has 0 length now.
 `NELEMENTS()` just returns the allocated memory for that array.

You should use a function for what you want to achieve:

```
int nElements(const char* x){

    int i=-1;
    while(x[++i]!=0);
    return i;
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: This is really confusing, with broken code.

Comment: Where does that `s` come from?

Comment: @UniCell that was just a mistake. Am in a hurry

Comment: Typo: "equals `"\0"`" means it would point to a *C-string* containing `0`. It simply "equals `'\0'`", which is exactly the same as `0` (and `0x000` and so on).

Comment: @Jongware it equals  setting the first and second element to 0. But yes, missleading

Comment: @Florian `x(++i)` is just wrong.

Comment: @unwind thanks for not just clarifying the typo. (one can easily get confused when coding in multiple languages daily)

Comment: @Florian Down-vote removed, although I think you should make `x` a `const char *` too, and `function` is hardly C so your code is still very strange. You can always test-compile online before posting if you're uncertain.

Comment: @unwind TNX! Definetly going to check the next time.